# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 (Xcode 4) // opengles.o

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, opengl, opengl-es

I'm making an xcode command tool application with external libraries and got some errors.

what i tried to resovle them :

- Build with different compiler
- remove The GLES folder and add it again
- Build it on 32 and 64

Am i missing something regarding the opengles.cpp ?

If you got any idea what can be done next please say so, below you can find all the info regarding the project and error. If you need more info i'm happy to assist you. Also if you know how to get the NiUsertracker sample from opnni compiled in xcode 4, it would also be a great help to solve this problem

The error :

[image]

The problem might have something to do with these files :

[image]

The info of the project setting (it's a command line tool not an app) :

[image]

Screenshot of the output when building

[image]

The build settings

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Usually when I get those kinds of errors, It's because I forgot to link with the library. The folder you got contains only headers; try to find the framework for OpenGL ES. (I think Xcode comes with a GLES framework, try searching.)

Comment: This strategy solved my problem when I was seeing these errors.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Run the commands manually in a terminal (Terminal.app) to find out exactly what the problem is:

```
[ 11:56 jon@hozbox ~ ]$ Ld /Users/olivierjanssens/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scene-anlidnesspxdbhblrrwqfwybphqj/Build/Products/Debug/scene normal x86_64
[ 11:56 jon@hozbox ~ ]$ cd /Users/olivierjanssens/Documents/xcode/scene
[ 11:56 jon@hozbox ~ ]$ setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7
[ 11:56 jon@hozbox ~ ]$ /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -L/Users/olivierjanssens/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scene-anlidnesspxdbhblrrwqfwybphqj/Build/Products/Debug -L/Users/olivierjanssens/Documents/xcode/scene/Libs -F/Users/olivierjanssens/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scene-anlidnesspxdbhblrrwqfwybphqj/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/olivierjanssens/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/scene-anlidnesspxdbhblrrwqfwybphqj/Build/Intermediates/scene.build/Debug/scene.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/scene.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 /usr/lib/libnimCodecs.dylib /usr/lib/libnimMockNodes.dylib /usr/lib/libnimRecorder.dylib /usr/lib/libOpenNI.dylib /usr/lib/libXnVFeatures.dylib /usr/lib/libXnVHandGenerator.dylib -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL /Users/olivierjanssens/Documents/xcode/scene/Libs/glut64.lib -o
```

After running the last command (`/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2`), it will show the reason for failing.

If the `setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7` command fails, replace `setenv` with `export` and put an `=` before the `10.7` like this:

```
[ 11:56 jon@hozbox ~ ]$ export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="10.7"
```

---

It seems like your missing a setting for your build configuration.  Possibly the app name (MyApp.app).  Check to make sure your not missing anything from the "Info" tab in the project settings window (just click the top item from the list of files on the left).

From [llvm-gcc man page](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/llvmgcc-2.8/):

> `-o filename` Specify the output file to be filename.

Comment: You might need to completly remove that egl framework from your project, then add it back in.  Sometimes frameworks get de-linked in xcode for no reason.

Comment: There is no egl framework. But there is a opengles.h file though. I removed all the files which i added to the project and then added them again. No difference . I added a screenshots of the folder with the files which i think might be responsible for the error.

Comment: It seems like your missing a setting for your build configuration. Possibly the app name (MyApp.app). Check to make sure your not missing anything from the "Info" tab in the project settings window (just click the top item from the list of files on the left).

Comment: I'm not developping an app, it is a command line tool . And i can't change the name. Though a project name is set

Comment: Can you include a screenshot or list of your build settings for the target?  Just the "basic" view should be fine, not "all".

Comment: ok i'ved added the screenshot, i also tried with another  compiler

Comment: It seems that there is an issue with the architecture you are building for and the glut32/64 libs.  Whats your architecture build settings?

Comment: Those are prebuild by openni/nite ,both are included and i've tried to build my project on 32 as 64 , both with the same results. I don't think that it has something to do with the architecture as the 2 versions are in the project (Even tried to compile it with them separately). My best guess is something with a library that is not included or added ... but i'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

remove the framework.And add it again.Quit the Xcode and relaunch it.

Comment: It is not a framework but a folder from another project. I did like you said an removed the folder added it again restarted xcode. But i'm affraid there  no difference