# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 os x lion

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, linker, cmake

When trying to compile a simple c++ test.cpp code with opencv 2.3.1 as as third
library, I get the following error message:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "_cvLoadImage", referenced from: 
>        _main in test.cpp.o 
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

For info, am using CMake for linking, and gcc 4.2.1 i686-apple-darwin11
obtained from Xcode 4.2. OpenCV had been installed using CMake:

ccmake ../sourcecode

Note please that I get a similar message when trying to compile SoQt
(coin3D), after commands ./configure & sudo make:

> . 
>   .
>   .
>
> "typeinfo for QWidget", referenced from:
>        typeinfo for SoQtThumbWheelin SoQtThumbWheel.o
>    "QWidget::staticMetaObject", referenced from:
>        SoQtThumbWheel::staticMetaObject        in SoQtThumbWheel.o 
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

The CMakeLists.txt of the main project is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)    
PROJECT(TOTO )

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${TOTO_SOURCE_DIR}/src/control)

SET(ALL_LIB_RAF  ${OPENCV_LIBRARIES}             
         Hello
          )

# FILEs to consider
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(main) 
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src )
```

While the CMakeLists.txt for test.cpp is:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(helloWorld test)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(helloWorld ${ALL_LIB_RAF} )
```

Perhaps the issue consists in the fact that OpenCV needs to be compiled in 64-bit (?). I found an interesting [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781198/compiling-opencv-code-on-a-64-bit-mac). But am wondering how that mights be applied to CMake.

Any help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like you are not linking against the library correctly. There are at least two similar questions on stackoverflow that deal with this issue, namely [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014334) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854798). Did you take a look at them? Furthermore, please supply more information about *how* you are compiling. Can you compile a simple OpenCV test program such as this one (taken from [their wiki](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Getting_started)):

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
  cvNamedWindow( "My Window", 1 );
  IplImage *img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 640, 480 ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
  CvFont font;
  double hScale = 1.0;
  double vScale = 1.0;
  int lineWidth = 1;
  cvInitFont( &font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX | CV_FONT_ITALIC,
              hScale, vScale, 0, lineWidth );
  cvPutText( img, "Hello World!", cvPoint( 200, 400 ), &font,
             cvScalar( 255, 255, 0 ) );
  cvShowImage( "My Window", img );
  cvWaitKey();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. <\p> Your code does not compile either. I saw the two links. The issue is that am linking with CMake. <\p> I think I need to recompile opencv with 64-bit. Please do you know how can we do it with CMake? I.e., which flags to specify?

Comment: I found this useful link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781198/compiling-opencv-code-on-a-64-bit-mac) But I did not find how to apply it to CMake

Comment: @polar Please add some more details to your original question. How did you try to compile the example code? stackoverflow needs more details in order to help you.

Comment: To compile and create the build:  ccmake ../project-source. I did not touch any flag.

Comment: @polar How do you want to compile the example above with this command? There's no `CMakeLists.txt`...

Comment: @polar I way implying that you did not specify all relevant information here ;) Did you do a `FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)` and added `${OpenCV_LIBS}` to your application via `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES`?

Comment: The first CMakeList.txt concerns test.cpp, while the second corresponds to the main project.

Comment: @polar Could you please add this information to your original question? This really badly formatted here and will not help others.

Comment: @polar Not really. Do you *want* to read any code that is formatted like that? Please take your time to update the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I generated this error when I accidentally combined separate target_link_libraries() in my CMakeLists.txt file when compiling with cmake.

Specifically, I took the correct:

```
target_link_libraries(
GradientComputer
)

target_link_libraries(
Overlap
PointAreaComputer
)
```

and combined them to create the incorrect:

```
target_link_libraries(
GradientComputer
Overlap
PointAreaComputer
)
```